# Manga where the main character killed two intruders with a katana, but got stabbed with a short sword and transferred to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I still remember a lot of what happened in the manga, but can't figure out the title. The main character is experienced in using the katana and also doesn't think of criminals as humans. But after getting transferred to another world with both weapons, he talked to the sword and ran across some bandits. He killed one stealthily and killed all the others and gained a companion.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, was the MC originally from the modern era or a previous century?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[The Cursed Sword Master’s Harem Life: By the Sword, For the Sword.](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ymyb7cd/makenshi-no-maken-niyoru-maken-no-tame-no-harem-life)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/makenshi-no-maken-niyoru-maken-no-tame-no-harem-life):

> An ever-righteous and sword-loving high schooler, Fujinomiya Soujirou is fatally stabbed by a robber during a home invasion. However, on the crossroads between life and death, "God" asks him if he wants to live a little longer. Clutching one of his prized swords, Soujirou agrees to a (cheatless) new life. Sent to another world, his only possessions are a talking sword "Hotarumaru" and the sword that took his life, "Sakura". He is also given the job title of "Cursed Sword Master", granting him the ability to bring out the "personality" of a sword. With a new realm of possibilities laid out before him, he sets forth on a journey to raise a harem of katanas, while begrudgingly hunting monsters and helping those in need.

A Japanese high school student named Fujinomiya Soujirou kills two robbers with a katana during a home invasion, but is stabbed in the back with a short sword during the incident, and dies as well. His soul encounters a mysterious being in the afterlife, who tells him that he's going to be sent to another world, and that he can bring anything he can hold in his hand along with him. Souji chooses the two swords.

He then wakes up in another world with the two swords strapped to his waist. In this world, the katana begins talking to him, and tells him that its name is Hotarumaru, which Souji associates with a famous and valuable sword that was lost during the Pacific War. The short sword doesn't speak, so Souji decides to name it himself, and picks the name 'Sakura.'

After travelling on foot for a while, Souji hears screams and runs toward them, where he spots a young woman surrounded by a group of leering bandits. There's also a wagon nearby, and one of the bandits is inside it, copulating with a woman's corpse. Souji sneaks over to the wagon and uses the katana to slit that bandit's throat without anyone else noticing. He then walks up behind the other bandits and slaughters them without hesitation or mercy.

After the bandits have all been slain, Souji introduces himself to the young woman, Sistina, who thanks him for his help and accompanies him on subsequent adventures.

[image]

[image]